# javascript variable is undefined after Initialized

Tags: javascript, asp.net, undefined

I have below code, it's too simple

```
var Height = <%= Height %>,
    _height;                       

console.log(Height); // in my test, I got 800

    if(Height > 800){      

        _height = 450;
    }
    else {
       _height = 330;
    }
    console.log(_height); // it will log 'undefined'
```

What is the wrong part?

Comment: ok replacing `<%= Height %>` with `800` and `801` both work fine for me now.

Comment: when I Initialized `_height` in declaration (for example 300), the last `console.log` give me 300 !

Comment: Use `if(parseInt(Height>800)` or `parseFloat`.

Comment: I did, but the problem is still there !! I didn't see something like that before !

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo at (Missing letter)

```
heigh = 450;
```

so, try the code below:

```
var Height = <%= Height %>,
        _height;                       

    console.log(Height); // in my test, I got 800

        if(Height > 800){      

            _height = 450;
        }
        else {
           _height = 330;
        }
        console.log(_height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert `Height` to int or float then compare

```
if(parseInt(Height)>800)
```

or

```
if(parseFloat(Height)>800)
```

Comment: not if(parseInt(Height>800).. It must be if (parseInt(Height) > 800).

Answer (score 0):

use `if (parseInt(Height) > 800)` instead of simply checking `if(Height > 800)`. Its working fine.